# Connect to Hbase from Python and happybase / Thrift

Tags: python, hadoop, hbase, thrift, happybase

I have installed Cloudera Manager Express 5.9.0 installed HBase, with Thrift server running on port 9090 on CentOS 7.3 in a VirtualBox vm.

Please help in figuring out why I am unable to successfully interface via happybase, or help identify next steps to pursue.

I am an experienced Java programmer, learning Python.  I have experience using Hbase from Java using the native interface, although not in this specific environment.

- I have validated that I can use hbase shell to create tables, insert data, etc.
- I have validated that 9090 (thrift) is listening and accepting connections.
- I think I have validated that the Thrift server is running with the same protocol/transport settings as the happybase connection parameters.

Python Script taken virtually directly from happybase howto:

```
import happybase

connection = happybase.Connection(host='localhost',port=9090,transport='buffered', protocol='compact')

connection.create_table('mytable',
    {'cf1': dict(max_versions=10),
     'cf2': dict(max_versions=1, block_cache_enabled=False),
     'cf3': dict(),  # use defaults
    }
)
```

Error Message, which I can't find great reference for:

```
[root@data1 ~]# python testhbase.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testhbase.py", line 10, in <module> 'cf3': dict(),  # use defaults
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/happybase/connection.py", line 311, in create_table
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/thriftpy/thrift.py", line 198, in _req return self._recv(_api)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/thriftpy/thrift.py", line 210, in _recv fname, mtype, rseqid = self._iprot.read_message_begin()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/thriftpy/protocol/compact.py", line 147, in read_message_begin % proto_id)
thriftpy.protocol.exc.TProtocolException: TProtocolException(type=4)
 [root@data1 ~]#
```

I have Thift web service manager running on port 9095 which reports:

```
HBase Version   1.2.0-cdh5.9.0, rUnknown    HBase version and revision
Thrift Impl Type    threadpool  Thrift RPC engine implementation type chosen by this Thrift server
Compact Protocol    true    Thrift RPC engine uses compact protocol
Framed Transport    false   Thrift RPC engine uses framed transport
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: are you sure the thrift 1 (not thrift2) daemon is used, with the right protocol and transport?

Comment: Wouter - bet you are right.  I was not aware of Thrift1/2 differences, and lack of Thrift² happybase support.   I will accept answer if you post as an answer.

Comment: hi, another related question - does hbase not require username/password to connect like any other database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess you are not using the supported version of the thrift daemon.

are you sure the thrift 1 (not thrift2) daemon is used, with the right protocol and transport?

Comment: Happybase only supports Thrift1.  For python support for Thrift2, try this:  https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-examples/src/main/python/thrift2/DemoClient.py

Comment: @wouterbolsterlee Where can I see if my hbase installation is using Thrift1 or Thrift2?

Answer (score 4):

Happybase only supports Thrift1.

For python support for hbase using Thrift2, try this:
https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-examples/src/main/python/thrift2/DemoClient.py

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after spending 40+ hours I figured out that in Cloudera VM:

`settings->network->advance->port forwarding`

You need to add new port 9090 and 9095(optional) to make it work.

For some reason, this port was not added by default in Cloudera image